# Send Data from Parent Component to Child Component generated from route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've been trying to send data from Parent component to Child component which was generated using a router link . 
What i want to send to the child component is Start Date and End Date which i fetch from Date picker.

```
<div id='startDate' class="panel panel-info">Start Date:<ng2-datepicker [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="startDate"></ng2-datepicker></div>
<div id='endDate' class="panel panel-info">End Date:<ng2-datepicker [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="endDate"></ng2-datepicker></div>
<button (click)="DateChanged()">Go</button>

<nav>
    <a routerLink="/Data-status" routerLinkActive="active">Data Status</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

On hitting the button go , i want the data to be available on the component table .

I call an api using the start date and end date in my child component which will fetch me the table data.

i tried @Input() but for that i need to define the selector in my parent component

How can i proceed ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read this, it will clear your doubts and offers you great examples on how to proceed: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: @SrAxi Thank you for the Reply . I'll give the docs a shot :)